# SQL of group by in order by

Tags: sql, oracle

```
[Raw data]
A  B    C 
1  10   1 
1  10   2
2  20   3
2  20   4
1  100  5
1  100  6

[Wanted result]
A    SUM_OF_B
1    20
2    40
1    200
```

It's unuseful that the query has the simple 'group by' clause and 'dense_rank over partition by' because grouping works all rows. However I want grouping in state of ordering. How do I write the proper query?

Comment: Also, what is the ordering based on?  Are you assuming that the raw data already comes in a certain order (bad idea)?  Or do you sort by column B?

Comment: @sstan thank you. I modified the question. Adding column C.

Comment: Not an Oracle wizard, but this should be an acceptableish adaptation of the linked answer: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/58dcd/16

Comment: @Amadan thank you but your query doesn't work on my oracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to identify the groups of adjacent records.  You can actually do this by using a difference of row numbers approach -- assuming that `c` orders the rows.  The difference is constant for consecutive values of `a` that are the same:

```
select a, sum(b)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by c) -
              row_number() over (partition by a order by c)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by grp, a
order by min(c);
```